# Make a Class or ID to stop listening to a global scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liferay

So im working in this page https://www.pacificotest.com.pe/.
- When someone scroll the page, the box that appears when you type "Clinica "
move is not absolute, and when I change it to absolute it keep moving anyway.
- Is there any way that I can make that box to not listen to the scroll event, that way it wont move around.

[When you scroll down a little bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiCPd.jpg)
[When you scroll top fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uu45.jpg)

I kinda solved the second issue with the following code:

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.autocomplete-suggestions').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('fix-searcher-' + (i + 1));
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  const emergencyBarHeight = 40;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= emergencyBarHeight) {
    $searcher1.removeClass("fix-searcher1").addClass("fixed");
    $searcher2.removeClass("fix-searcher2").addClass("fixed2");
  } else {
    $searcher1.removeClass("fixed").addClass("fix-searcher1");
    $searcher2.removeClass("fixed2").addClass("fix-searcher2");
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fixed{
position: fixed ! important;
top:100px ! important;
}

.fixed2{
position: absolute ! important;
top:430px ! important;
z-index:100 ! important;
}

.fix-searcher1{
position: fixed ! important;
top:140px ! important;
}

.fix-searcher2{
top:490px ! important;
z-index:100 ! important;
}
```

When i remove the scroll global event from all the document it solve the problem, but other elements will stop too, so im looking to stop the scroll only for the box.

Comment: tip: Dont use jquery anymore. Javascript can do everything jquery can do.

Comment: @Tay of course JS can do everything jquery does (jquery is a JS framework) - but your advise to not use jquery is naive.  The point of using jquery is to simplify and standardize your JS for common tasks

Comment: @Tay i agree and disagree, once you load jQuery for a solid and ready made plugin , then, use the wheel ;) .

Comment: @blurfus its unreadable in large amounts, not to mention it looks like PHP puked on JS.

lets not mention that your hooking a fat library to get a little $() selector that can be achieved in seconds with bind or arrow expressions.

Comment: @Tay we can agree that jQuery has a reason to exist and that there are some use cases when it is totally overkill - in terms of looks, it's an opinion like any other (preferences are always a funny thing so no point in debating that) - If you take aside the use cases when you don't need it, it is a very popular framework that actually can save you a fair amount of manual JS wrangling (hello xhr error handling) and DOM manipulation (hello styles properties/attributes)  - so choose your tools properly instead of religiously